# DML for SOQL Result +Limits

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to query list of records, make changes and update the same. I see two approaches here:

Approach 1:

```
 List<Account> listOfAccToUpdate=new List<Account>();
for(Account acc: [SELECT field1 FROM Account WHERE Rba__c=true]){
    acc.field1=true;
    listOfAccToUpdate.add(acc);
}
update listOfAccToUpdate;
```

Approach 2:

```
List<Account> listOfAccToUpdate=new List<Account>();
for(List<Account> accList: [SELECT field1 FROM Account WHERE Rba__c=true]){
    for(Account acc: accList){
        acc.field1=true;
    }
    if(listOfAccToUpdate.size()+accList.size()<=10000){
        listOfAccToUpdate.addAll(accList);
    }
    else{
        update listOfAccToUpdate;
        listOfAccToUpdate.clear();
        listOfAccToUpdate.addAll(accList)
    }
    
    
}
```

Question- Is Approach 2 better since we do not know if the query returns more than 10  k records.
Also we may save on heap size on second approach, though syntactically I am doing a DML in a loop

Answer (score 4):

Since there's a limit of 10k records *per transaction*, it doesn't matter if you limit yourself to 10,000 records at once. You're still limited to 10,000 rows. Your strategy should therefore be more like "if more than 10000 rows, jump to a queueable or batchable method".

In addition, your queries are limited to just 50,000 rows before a governor limit is breached (again, *per transaction*, not just per query), which will generally fit in heap space unless you query many fields per object, in which case, you might want to move to a smaller size, such as 1,000 rows per DML operation instead.

In general, if you're worried about a large data skew, fire off a batchable or queueable, otherwise don't worry about the differences. The for-record-list method is slightly more efficient, but what's even faster is to use the first method *without* copying the records:

```
 List<Account> listOfAccToUpdate=[SELECT field1 FROM Account WHERE Rba__c=true];
for(Account acc: listOfAccToUpdate){
    acc.field1=true;
}
update listOfAccToUpdate;
```

This loop has the best performance characteristics, as you avoid reallocating heap excessively. See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/227273/2984), [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/282831/2984), [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/224544/2984), [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/129712/2984), [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/180650/2984) (not mine), [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/112502/2984) (also not mine), [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/143891/2984) (more optimization, not mine), and other [performance](/questions/tagged/performance) questions for more performance-related questions.

You may note some contradictory answers; the exact performance characteristics of Salesforce tends to change over time, so doing your own testing is advisable, but even more importantly, **don't worry about micro-optimizations**, it may not actually matter in the long run, or might even be optimized away in a future release.

The only thing you *should* take away from this answer is that the 10k limit is a hard limit, so you must be prepared to branch off to a Queueable or Batchable to update more than 10k records if you're concerned about the possibility.